# http response from recv() is missing raw/binary data in the body C++ sockets

Tags: c++, http, sockets, http-headers

working on a http client that downloads data from a website using HTTP/1.1 (not https on port 443). The program is working for the most part, but when I attempt to write the data to a file, the data in the file does not match with the data when I physically save the file from a browser. Here is the code below:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

string resolveToIPAddress(string, string);
int getPortNum(string);
string getUrlPath(string);
string getDomain(string);
string getDomainWithFile(string);
string getUrlWithNoPort(string);
string getFileFromURL(string);
string getFilePath(string);
bool hasHTTPProtocol(string);
bool hasPortNum(string);
bool checkIfValidProtocol(string);


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    //Create a file to be opened for output
    ofstream out_file;
    out_file.open("output", ios::out | ios::binary);
    int connection_port = 0, send_req, recv_req;
    string ip_addr = "", domain = "", ipFromDomain = "", file_to_get = "", http_response = "";
    
    ip_addr = argv[1]; //point ip address argument to the 2nd indice in the arguments

    //Check if http is valid
    if(hasHTTPProtocol(ip_addr) == true) {
             //if there is a port number, Get port number (extract it from URL)
        if(hasPortNum(ip_addr)) {
            connection_port = getPortNum(ip_addr);
            domain = getDomain(ip_addr);
        }
            //if there is no port number, set default port number = 80 and set domain to truncated ip address
        else {
            connection_port = 80;
            domain = getDomain(ip_addr);
        }
        
        file_to_get = getFileFromURL(ip_addr);
        //For Testing purposes only
        //cout << "Domain: " << domain << endl;
        //cout << getDomainWithFile(ip_addr) << endl;
        //cout << "URL without port: " << getUrlWithNoPort(ip_addr) << endl;
        //cout << "URL Path: " << getUrlPath(ip_addr);
        //cout << "Path and File: " << getFilePath(ip_addr) << endl;
        //cout << "Domain and File: " << getDomainWithFile(ip_addr) << endl;
        // cout << "Port Number: " << connection_port << endl;
        // cout << "File requested: " << file_to_get << endl;
        //resolve domain to ipAddress
        ipFromDomain = resolveToIPAddress(domain, to_string(connection_port));
        //Connect to iP Address with port and return metadata
        
        //Create the socket
        int http_client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        // connect address and contain socket
        struct sockaddr_in connection_addr;
        connection_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; //set the addressfamily type to INET 
        connection_addr.sin_port = htons(connection_port); //set socket to parsed port number
        //cout << "ip address: " << ipFromDomain << endl; //checking to see if ip address is well converted
        inet_aton(ipFromDomain.c_str(), &connection_addr.sin_addr); //convert ip address from IPV4 notation string and store it into structure

        //Connect to server address
        if(connect(http_client_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &connection_addr, sizeof(connection_addr)) != 0) {
            out_file << "NOCONNECTION" << endl;
            out_file.close();
            exit(0);
        }

        //Logic for HTTP GET Request
        string http_request = "GET /" + getFilePath(ip_addr) + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:" + domain + "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
        //cout << http_request << endl;
        send_req = send(http_client_socket, http_request.c_str(), http_request.length(), 0);
        if ( send_req != http_request.length() ) { std::cerr << "Oops on send\n"; }
        char buff[BUFSIZ];
        int n;
        while ( (n=recv(http_client_socket, buff, sizeof(buff), 0)) > 0 ) {
            http_response.append(buff, n);
        }
        
        //Testing
        //cout << http_response << endl;

        //Test for 404, if there is a 404 then close the program and exit with "FILENOTFOUND" in output file
        if(http_response.find("HTTP/1.1 404") != string::npos) {
            out_file << "FILENOTFOUND" << endl;
            out_file.close();
            exit(0);
        }

        const char * http_body_data = strstr(http_response.c_str(), "\r\n\r\n");
        if(http_body_data) {
            http_body_data += 4;
        }

        //out_file << http_response;
        //close the file
        out_file << http_body_data;
        out_file.close();

        //close the socket
        close(http_client_socket);
    } else {
        out_file << "INVALIDPROTOCOL" << endl;
        out_file.close();
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}

string getUrlWithNoPort(string url) {
    if(hasHTTPProtocol(url))
        return url.substr(7, url.length() - 7);
    return url;
}
//Get URL without port and path
string getDomain(string url) {
    string urlWithoutPortandPath = "";
    int i = 0;
    //Check if full URL has a protocol
    if (hasHTTPProtocol(url)) {
        //if it has a protocol truncate the protocol from FQDN
        i = 7;
        while (url[i] != '/') {

        
        //for (int i = 7; i < url.length(); i++) {
            if (url[i] == ':') {
                break;
            }
            urlWithoutPortandPath += url[i];
            i++;
        //}
        }
        return urlWithoutPortandPath;
    }
    
    //if it does not have a protocol remove port number and path
    while (url[i] != '/') {
    //for (int i = 0; i < url.length(); i++) {
        if (url[i] == ':') {
            break;
        }
        urlWithoutPortandPath += url[i];
        i++;
    } 
    return urlWithoutPortandPath;
}

string getDomainWithFile(string url) {
    string urlWithoutPortandPath = "";
    //Check if full URL has a protocol
    if (hasHTTPProtocol(url)) {
        //if it has a protocol truncate the protocol from FQDN
        for (int i = 7; i < url.length(); i++) {
            if (url[i] == ':') {
                break;
            }
            urlWithoutPortandPath += url[i];
        }
        return urlWithoutPortandPath;
    }
    
    //if it does not have a protocol remove port number and path
   
    for (int i = 0; i < url.length(); i++) {
        if (url[i] == ':') {
            break;
        }
        urlWithoutPortandPath += url[i];
    } 
    return urlWithoutPortandPath;
}

bool hasHTTPProtocol(string url) {
    string httpProtocol = url.substr(0, 7);
    if(httpProtocol == "http://")
        return true;
    return false;
}

int getPortNum(string url) {
    string port = "";
    int portNum, portIdx = 0, pathIdx = 0, portEndIdx = 0;
    if(hasHTTPProtocol(url)) {
        for(int i = 7; i < url.length(); i++) {
            if (url[i] == ':')
                portIdx = i + 1;
        }
    }
    

    string fromPortToPath = url.substr(portIdx, url.length() - portIdx);
    //cout << "Port to Path: " << fromPortToPath << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < fromPortToPath.length(); i++) {
        if (fromPortToPath[i] == '/') {
            pathIdx = i + 1;
            portEndIdx = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    port = fromPortToPath.substr(0, portEndIdx);
    portNum = stoi(port);
    return portNum;
}

string getUrlPath(string url) {
    string urlPath = "";
    int pathIdx = 0, portIdx = 0, portEndIdx = 0;
    if(hasHTTPProtocol(url)) {
         for(int i = 7; i < url.length(); i++) {
            if (url[i] == ':')
                portIdx = i + 1;
        }
    }
   
    string fromPortToPath = url.substr(portIdx, url.length() - portIdx);
    cout << "Port to Path: " << fromPortToPath << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < fromPortToPath.length(); i++) {
        if (fromPortToPath[i] == '/') {
            pathIdx = i + 1;
            portEndIdx = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    urlPath = fromPortToPath.substr(portEndIdx + 1, fromPortToPath.length() - pathIdx );
    return urlPath; 
}

bool hasPortNum(string url) {
    if(hasHTTPProtocol(url)) {
        for (int i = 7; i < url.length(); i++) {
            if (url[i] == ':')
                return true;
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < url.length(); i++) {
            if (url[i] == ':')
                return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

//Resolves a string hostname e.g. google.com into an ipaddress (practically a DNS function)
string resolveToIPAddress(string urlString, string portNum) {
    struct addrinfo hints, *results;
    struct addrinfo *result;
    int error, sock_id;
    string numericalIPS[100];
    //set all bits in hints to zero
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if((error = getaddrinfo(urlString.c_str(), portNum.c_str(), &hints, &results)) != 0) {
        cout << "error " << error << ":" << gai_strerror(error) << endl;
    }

    int i = 0;
    //loop through results
    for(result = results; result != nullptr; result = result->ai_next) {
        struct sockaddr_in *ip_addr;
        ip_addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)result->ai_addr;
        numericalIPS[i] = inet_ntoa(ip_addr->sin_addr);
        i++;
    }
    return numericalIPS[0];
}

string getFileFromURL(string url) {
    int idxToFile;
    string file_request;
    string path_to_file = getDomainWithFile(url);
    for (int i = 0; i < path_to_file.length(); i++) {
        if(path_to_file[i] == '/') {
            idxToFile = i + 1;
        }
    }
    file_request = path_to_file.substr(idxToFile, path_to_file.length() - idxToFile);
    return file_request;
}

string getFilePath(string url) {
    string domainPathAndFile = getDomainWithFile(url);
    string pathAndFile;
    int idxToPath;
    for (int i = 0; i < domainPathAndFile.length(); i++) {
        if(domainPathAndFile[i] == '/') {
            idxToPath = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    pathAndFile = domainPathAndFile.substr(idxToPath, domainPathAndFile.length() - idxToPath);
    return pathAndFile;


}
```

I used this website as a testing medium: http://www.testingmcafeesites.com/testcat_ac.html

When I do the following:

```
wget http://www.testingmcafeesites.com/testcat_ac.html
```

I get the following:

```
<html>
      <head>
            <title>URL for testing - Category Art/Culure</title>
      </head>

      <body>
            <code>
              http://www.testingmcafeesites.com/testcat_ac.html<br>
              <br>

                  This is an example URL which should be categorized as an art/culture website with a minimal risk reputation score.<br>
                  This page simply displays this text without any specific content on it, it is just for testing purpose.<br>
                  <br>
                  <b>If you can see this text, it was not blocked by any filter!</b><br>
                  <br>
            </code>
      </body>
</html>
```

However, with my program, I get the following and there are spaces as well in the first couple of lines:

```
<html>
      <head>
            <title>URL for testing - Category Art/Culure</title>
      </head>

      <body>
            <code>
              http://www.testingmcafeesites.com/testcat_ac.html<br>
              <br>

                  This is an example URL which should be categorized as an art/culture website with a minimal risk reputation score.<br>
                  This page simply displays this text without any specific content on it, it is just for testing purpose.<br>
                  <br>
                  <b>If you can see this text, it was not blocked by any filter!</b><br>
                  <br>
            </code>
      </body>
```

Sadly, this platform does not illustrate the spaces. What can I do to improve the body of the http response in my code. I was able to remove the header of the response with strstr but I feel as if I am missing something else. Thanks!

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. You get the correct dump by `cout << http_response << endl;`. Remove all code above this line, assign the dump to `http_response ` and remove all other unrelated code.

Comment: Your code does not account for this header: `Content-Length: 9509` wget sees that and stops reading after 9509 bytes. Your code just keeps reading until the socket is closed by the other end.

Comment: @MartinYork in general, yes, that is a good point to pay attention to. However, the code is requesting `Connection: close`, so the server is going to close the connection at the end of the response.

Comment: @Ubuntuer MartinYork has a point, though. You are not actually parsing the server's response in any meaningful way. I suggest you have a read through [my past answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A65863+http+pseudo) on this topic, I've posted quite a few answers that demonstrate the proper way HTTP messages should be processed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use

```
wget http://www.testingmcafeesites.com/testcat_ac.html -O testcat_ac.html
```

Open the file `testcat_ac.html` in a hex editor and you see it contains a lot of unprintable characters, null bytes. Dealing with such data as a C string `http_response.c_str()` is not productive. Use `std::string` equivalent functions.

Comment: Does C++ have an equivalent to strstr where I can remove the header portion of the http response? Thanks!

Comment: erase from 0 till find + 4.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your comment my friend.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, use the find function to get the position of the string and then use substr to trim the other portion. That works for the most part, but I think my file has 2 enter gaps (when a user hits enter twice at the top of the file. I notice this when I "cat" the output.